# From binary sequence to time series frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have data-set which contains data from presence sensors which are stored as binary sequence in a frequency of 1 hour. 
Sensor checks the presence every 2 minutes and stores it in binary sequence every hour(0 for no presence detected, 1 for presence detected), which means one data-point has 30 digits.
Data-point for one sensor for one hour looks like this 001111110111100000001000000100.

I would like to create dataframe which has frequency of 2 minutes and for each sensor, column which indicates presence or no presence (1 or 0).

Any ideas how to do it?

```
MACAddress          f8:f0:05:d0:ee:29              f8:f0:05:d0:f1:0b                f8:f0:05:d0:f1:1d   
2019-04-02 09:00:00 100100000000000000000000000000 100000000000001111111111010111   111111110111111111111110110000
2019-04-02 09:00:00 001110110000000000000000011111 111110000000000000111111110100 111010110011111111111011111111
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the values strings? (Guessing from the existence of a leading zero.)

Comment: I think it is a good idea to not only describe in words how you'd like the resulting dataframe to look, but also give an example. Doing that makes it easier for people trying to help you to make sure they give you the answer you actually want. Also, do you want one dataframe per each hour or have all of the transformed rows in one dataframe?

Comment: Also shouldn't the second row have `10:00:00` as time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my proposal, hope it helps:

Build some sample data:

```
dd = {'f8:f0:05:d0:ee:29': ['100100000000000000000000000000', '001110110000000000000000011111'],
      'f8:f0:05:d0:f1:0b': ['100000000000001111111111010111', '111110000000000000111111110100'],
      'f8:f0:05:d0:f1:1d': ['111111110111111111111110110000', '001110110000000000000000011111']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dd, index=['2019-04-02 09:00:00', '2019-04-02 10:00:00'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Solution:

```
expanded = df.apply(lambda series: series.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).stack())
expanded.index = expanded.index.get_level_values(0) + (expanded.index.get_level_values(1)*2).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do it using the vectorized functions, which means you will have to do it using something normally to be avoided, iterating manually over the rows using `df.iterrows`.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_subtimes(df):
    previous = df.index[0] - (df.index[1] - df.index[0])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        yield pd.DataFrame(row.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x))).to_dict(),
                           index=pd.date_range(previous, index, freq="2T")[1:])
        previous = index


df = pd.DataFrame([["100100000000000000000000000000", "100000000000001111111111010111", "111111110111111111111110110000"],
                   ["001110110000000000000000011111", "111110000000000000111111110100", "111010110011111111111011111111"]],
                  columns=["f8:f0:05:d0:ee:29", "f8:f0:05:d0:f1:0b", "f8:f0:05:d0:f1:1d"],
                  index=pd.to_datetime(["2019-04-02 09:00:00", "2019-04-02 10:00:00"]))

print(pd.concat(get_subtimes(df)))
```

Result:

```
                     f8:f0:05:d0:ee:29  f8:f0:05:d0:f1:0b  f8:f0:05:d0:f1:1d
2019-04-02 08:02:00                  1                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:04:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:06:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:08:00                  1                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:10:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:12:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:14:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:16:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:18:00                  0                  0                  0
2019-04-02 08:20:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:22:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:24:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:26:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:28:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:30:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:32:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:34:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:36:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:38:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:40:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:42:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:44:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:46:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:48:00                  0                  1                  0
2019-04-02 08:50:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 08:52:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 08:54:00                  0                  0                  0
2019-04-02 08:56:00                  0                  1                  0
2019-04-02 08:58:00                  0                  1                  0
2019-04-02 09:00:00                  0                  1                  0
2019-04-02 09:02:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:04:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:06:00                  1                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:08:00                  1                  1                  0
2019-04-02 09:10:00                  1                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:12:00                  0                  0                  0
2019-04-02 09:14:00                  1                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:16:00                  1                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:18:00                  0                  0                  0
2019-04-02 09:20:00                  0                  0                  0
2019-04-02 09:22:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:24:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:26:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:28:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:30:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:32:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:34:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:36:00                  0                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:38:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:40:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:42:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:44:00                  0                  1                  0
2019-04-02 09:46:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:48:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:50:00                  0                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:52:00                  1                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:54:00                  1                  0                  1
2019-04-02 09:56:00                  1                  1                  1
2019-04-02 09:58:00                  1                  0                  1
2019-04-02 10:00:00                  1                  0                  1
```

Comment: I got this error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (32, 30), indices imply (32, 1470)
Anyway the other solution worked, but thanks anyway